# Add text longer than 50 characters to Access text box on click

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this code in an Access form:

```
Private Sub btnGenerateName_Click()
    Me.txtName = Me.Family & " " & Me.Model & " " & Me.DimensionsText
End Sub
```

If the concatenated string is longer than 50 characters when I'm clicking the button throws an error:

> "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to
>   add. Try inserting or pasting less data."

Isn't the text box length 255? Why I can't insert longer text?

Comment: Is the text box bounded to database field? do you have enough length on that field?

Comment: No, it isn't bounded to database field, but the other three from where I am concatenating the results, are bounded.

Comment: It must be bound to a field since the error clearly states that the FIELD is too small. Double check.

Comment: Like everyone said, check your Table field. It is probably a Text field. You can change it to Memo field in order to store more characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can find what they are explaining by **do**ing **the following**:

1. Go to the **supporting table's Design View**
2. **Select** the **field**
3. Select **Field Size** limit (By default it is set to 50.)

[image]